# Automaticaly downloadable invoice pdf

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to create an option to download a pdf file having an invoice with the following properties in the django database admin:

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

from appsystem.models import Outlet
from core.models import Item, Supplier
from location.models import Warehouse, Zone, Section, Level


class MainPurchases(models.Model):
    METHOD_A = 'CASH'
    METHOD_B = 'CREDIT'

    PAYMENT_METHODS = [
        (METHOD_A, 'CASH'),
        (METHOD_B, 'CREDIT'),
    ]

    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    paid_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need this to be a printable invoice slip with the specified values but I just can't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's really two questions. How to generate pdf from data in the DB, and how to deliver it to a web client (browser).

In answer to the second,  here's a view I wrote earlier

```
from io import BytesIO

def pdfview( request, pk):

    quote = get_object_or_404( Quote, pk=pk)  # object to build pdf from

    pdf = build_pdf( quote)

    iobuf = BytesIO( bytearray(pdf.output( dest='S' ), encoding='latin-1'))

    response = HttpResponse( iobuf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'
            ] = 'inline; filename={}.pdf'.format(quote.quotenumber) 

    # inline; will ask for an immediate display  of the content
    # attachment; will offer options to the user, including save without display
    # exact details are  browser-specific.

return response
```

As for build_pdf, I was using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)

```
from fpdf import FPDF

def build_pdf( quote):
    pdf = FPDF() 

    # pdf.this( ...)
    # pdf.that( ...)

    # much later, when done
    return pdf
```

Comment: Well, thanks. I haven't received any answers on this for quite some time anywhere.